# How to fit the rising and falling flank of a curve seperately and determine the point of intersection?

Tags: python, interpolation, curve

I'm looking for a way to fit the rising flank of a curve (until 50% of max amplitude) and the falling flank (also the lower 50% of max amp) seperately with an exponential and determine their interpolated point of intersection.

For fitting until the maximum, where the coordinates of my curve are (x,y), I use:

```
def expinc(x, f0, a, k):
    return f0 + a*(1-np.exp(-k*x))

def mymask( y ):
    m = np.argmax(y)
    l = len(y)
    return m * [1] + ( l - m )* [ np.infty ]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(expinc, x, y, p0=[0, 1, 1], sigma=mymask(y), maxfev=10000)
```

Comment: Hi, please provide an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Let's assume a simple sinewave with x = np.arange(0,1,0.01) and y = np.sin(np.pi*x). I need to find the point where the two fits of the rising and the falling flank (where for both only the first 50% should be accounted for the fit) meet each other.

Comment: I see, but what is the problem programming wise? You seem to know how to fit a curve, so what is the issue?